# What do you call a horseman?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, word-comparison, military

I have seen that *miles* can be used for a footsoldier, but does *eques* or *equester* refer to a knight on horseback? Are there ant Classical examples of this? Are there any dictionaries that specifically define these terms as a *horseman* or *rider*? I'm sure there are plenty of Medieval and Renaissance words, but any from before?

Comment: Were the horsemen auxiliaries, like the peltasts (from the Balearic Islands)? If so 'Parthians' would be the word. Parthians fought with Pompey against Caesar at Philippi.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [eques](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=eques&la=la#lexicon) absolutely can mean knight:

> II. In partic.
>   A. **In milit. lang., a horse-soldier, trooper; opp. pedes, a foot-soldier, Caes. B. G. 1, 15, 3 (twice);** 1, 18 fin.; 1, 23, 2 et saep.; “opp. pedites,” id. ib. 1, 48, 5; 2, 24, 1; 4, 33, 3 et saep.; “opp. viri or homines, for pedites,” Liv. 21, 27; 9, 19: equites singulares Augusti, v. singularis.—
>   2. **Meton. or collect., horse-soldiers, cavalry: “plurimum in Aetolis equitibus praesidii fuit: is longe tum optimus eques in Graecia erat,” Liv. 33, 7 fin.;** 2, 20; 8, 38; Suet. Galb. 12; Flor. 2, 6, 13; Tac. A. 3, 46; 12, 29; id. H. 2, 89.—

*Equites* as a social class comes after the meaning of *eques* as a knight/horseman.

Comment: Also worth noting a derived word: [*equitatus, -us*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dequitatus1) = "cavalry" as a body

Answer (score 9):

The Lewis and Short entry for [*eques*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=eques&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) gives several classical use examples in the sense of "rider" or "horseman".
See [Caesar's *De Bello Gallico* 1.15](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0002:book=1:chapter=15&highlight=equitibus%2Cequitum), for example.
A foot soldier is [*pedes*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=pedes&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) (gen. *peditis*), whereas *miles* means a soldier in general.

*Eques* also means an individual from the class of knights.
In this context it refers more to a position in the society than fighting on horseback.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I think you beat me to it by about a minute! The more answers and explanations, the merrier.

Comment: Ah, oops, you're right. And agreed.