# How would one translate "unvanquished riders"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

*Invictus eques* seems to apply to [horsemen](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/what-do-you-call-a-horseman), but I'm looking for riders in general (or particularly motorcycle riders but I'm not expecting *that* in Classical Latin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salve. Latin goes far beyond the classical period. Words such as motorbike rider exist in the contemporary Latin vocabulary.

I came across the word "vector," which means "one who rides" (Elementary Lewis) or "one who is carried" (Cassell's), in both [Smith & Hall](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=sh21470) and Cassell's Latin Dictionary. From there, meanings such as "horseman" or even "motorcyclist" can be derived. A search in the [Lexicon Morganianum](http://lexicon.paideiainstitute.org/search/latin?search=cyclist) rendered "cyclist" as "birotarius," a derivative of *birota.* One could, from there, add the prefix *auto* to form "autobirotarius," which would be a derivative of *autobirota*.

I think either *vector, ōris m.* or *autobirotarius* could work.

For "unvanquished," I might use "invictus" as your translation uses.

This would render the phrase as "vectōrēs invictī" or "autobirotariī invictī."

Comment: We've also had the question about [what to call motorcycles](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16621/whats-the-latin-for-motorcycle).